# Is there a formula for deriving the trigonometric functions of 30 degrees?

Tags: trigonometry

I know that the angles $30^{\circ}$, $45^{\circ}$, and $60^{\circ}$ are "special angles", but I can only derive them by a method that my professor showed in class, by drawing triangles with side values of 1, 1, and $\sqrt2$ or $1$, $2$, and $\sqrt3$.

Is there another method? Maybe an algebraic formula?

Comment: For $30°$ (or $60°$) trig values I just imagine an equilateral triangle cut in half. So $\sin 30°=\frac 12$ and the rest follow through the usual identities.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: all angles being in the first quadrant, thus having positive $\sin, \cos\,$ values:

- $t=\sin(30^\circ) = \cos(60^\circ)=\cos(2 \cdot 30^\circ)=1 - 2 \sin^2(30^\circ) \implies 2t^2+t-1=0$
- $t=\sin(45^\circ) = \cos(45^\circ)=\sqrt{1 - \sin^2(45^\circ)} \implies 2t^2=1$

Answer (score 0):

To have the cosine of $\frac\pi6$, you can use the trigonometric formula
$$\cos3\theta=4\cos^3\theta-3\cos \theta,$$
which shows $\cos\frac\pi6$  satisfies the equation $4x^3-3x=0$. As we know it's positive, we can deduce its value solving this equation (it has $3$ real roots).

Similarly, $\cos \frac\pi 3$ satisfies the equation 
$$4x^3-3x=-1$$
but after you've calculated $\cos\frac\pi6$, you also can do some trigonometry and use the duplication formula:
$$\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1.$$